# Quick QuickSort implementation

Tags: performance-tuning, algorithm, sorting

I am playing with julialang and loving it, but at the same time noticed that they have [a benchmark comparison with Mathematica](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/). I have already submited a better version of `recursion_fibonacci` and now am looking into `recursion_quicksort`. I would like to find an implementation in Mathematica that is comparable to C-lang.

Currently, [the benchmark uses](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Microbenchmarks/blob/master/perf.nb) the following code

```
(* numeric vector sort *)

ClearAll[qsort];
(* qsort[ain_, loin_, hiin_] := Module[
    {a = ain, i = loin, j = hiin, lo = loin, hi = hiin, pivot},
    While[ i < hi,
        pivot = a[[BitShiftRight[lo + hi] ]];
        While[ i <= j,
            While[a[[i]] < pivot, i++];
            While[a[[j]] > pivot, j--];
            If[ i <= j,
                a[[{i,j}]] = a[[{j, i}]];
                i++; j--;
            ];
        ];
        If[ lo < j, a = qsort[a, lo, j] ];
        {lo, j} = {i, hi};
    ];
    a
]; *)
qsort = Compile[
    {{ain, _Real, 1}, {loin, _Integer}, {hiin, _Integer}},
    Module[
        {a = ain, i = loin, j = hiin, lo = loin, hi = hiin, pivot},
        While[ i < hi,
            pivot = a[[ Floor[(lo + hi)/2] ]];
            While[ i <= j,
                While[a[[i]] < pivot, i++];
                While[a[[j]] > pivot, j--];
                If[ i <= j,
                    a[[{i,j}]] = a[[{j, i}]];
                    i++; j--;
                ];
            ];
            If[ lo < j, a[[lo;;j]] = qsort[ a[[lo;;j]], 1, j - lo + 1] ];
            {lo, j} = {i, hi};
        ];
        a
    ]
];


ClearAll[sortperf];
sortperf[n_] := Module[{vec = RandomReal[1, n]}, qsort[vec, 1, n]];

test[OrderedQ[sortperf[5000]] ];
timeit[sortperf[5000], "recursion_quicksort"];
```

where there is compiled and uncompiled versions of quicksort algorithm. On my laptop the compiled version takes **10.3ms**, while uncompiled version takes **137.8ms**. I think there is space for improvement since the inbuilt method Sort[] takes only **0.379ms**.

How do we speed-up the quicksort algorithm? Bonus points if we don't use Compile[]

Helper functions to run the code above

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
If[ Length[CCompilers[]] > 0,
    $CompilationTarget = "C"
];

ClearAll[timeit];
SetAttributes[timeit, HoldFirst];
timeit[ex_, name_String] := Module[
    {t},
    t = Infinity;
    Do[
        t = Min[t, N[First[AbsoluteTiming[ex]]]];
        ,
        {i, 1, 5}
    ];
    If[$printOutput, Print["mathematica,", name, ",", t*1000];  ];
];

ClearAll[test];
SetAttributes[test, HoldFirst];
test[ex_] := Assert[ex];
On[Assert];
```

Comment: I would hardly expect any top-level interpreted code to compete with a highly optimized low-level implementation (i.e. the built in), especially if you don't want to compile it. I understand *your* interest in doing that for recreational / educational purposes though. What strategies have you tried / would you like to implement to speed that up?

Comment: For the `recursive_fibonacci`, I assume you use memoization and this is not what the Julia-team wanted to measure with this test. This test is supposed to measure the timing of recursive calls which are horribly slow in Mathematica. I've been there myself when I saw the testing code and asked, who on earth would implement fib like that. As it turns out, for their purpose it is the right way to do it.

Comment: @halirutan I put the function into Module[], which should not allow any memorisation. [Commit is here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Microbenchmarks/pull/15/commits/3990dac03c036117c30699d243145b8547babfce). Any thoughts?

Comment: Karolis, The [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) that @halirutan mentioned is the `recFib[n_] := recFib[n] = ...` bit in the linked code. You are saving the results of previous calls to `recFib`. Wrapping the code in a `Module` does not change that. Try and calculate `recFib[30]` with and without the `... recFib[n] = ...` bit in the definition, and you will see what a *tremendous* difference that makes.

Comment: @MarcoB I see your point. Without this trick Mathematica is painfully slow

Comment: Also the `matmul` example in the [Julia benchmarks](https://julialang.org/benchmarks) is complete bogos. `Total[Unitize[A.ConjugateTranspose[A] - 200], 2] == 0` performs the task in a tenth of time. Benchmarking matrix multiplication is ridiculous anyways as any reasonable language would delegate that to BLAS routines. The `mandel` implementation is not `Listable`. Using `Compile` with options `CompilationTarget -> "C",
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` would make it 10(!) times faster, bringing us much closer to the C performance.

Comment: @Karolis "Without this trick Mathematica is painfully slow" -- that is "a trick" that comes from the inherent properties of Mathematica's language. It can be seen as a manifestation of its core design principles. (Rule-based programming.) Other languages do not allow so readily dynamic increments of function definitions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also got angry about those randomly picked and ill-implemented benchmarks by the Julia team. I appreciate their efforts (jit compilers *are* useful), but the Fibonacci example was straight away ridiculous.

Here is a compiled quick sort implementation that employs a stack in order to avoid recursive calls. The problem with recursion in `CompiledFunction`s is that it needs to call the main evaluator - and such calls are notoriously slow. I synthesized this implementation from the benchmark implementation and from [this guide on geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/).

Admittedly, one may argue whether this is still a "pure" Mathematica implementation or not (imho, it is rather C), but the Julia team also employed `Compile`. Hence, once started, one has to do that correctly.

```
quicksortiterative = Compile[{{ain, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{iter, l, h, a, stack, top, x, i, j, ai, aj},
    a = ain;
    top = 0;
    stack = Table[0, {Length[a] + 1}];
    stack[[++top]] = 1;
    stack[[++top]] = Length[a];
    While[top >= 1,
     h = Compile`GetElement[stack, top--];
     l = Compile`GetElement[stack, top--];
     x = Compile`GetElement[a, l + Quotient[h - l, 2]];
     i = l;
     j = h;
     While[i <= j,
      ai = Compile`GetElement[a, i];
      While[ai < x, ai = Compile`GetElement[a, ++i]];
      aj = Compile`GetElement[a, j];
      While[aj > x, aj = Compile`GetElement[a, --j]];
      If[i <= j,
       a[[i++]] = aj;
       a[[j--]] = ai;
       ];
      ];
     If[j > l, stack[[++top]] = l; stack[[++top]] = j];
     If[i < h, stack[[++top]] = i; stack[[++top]] = h];
     ];
    a
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

To my own surpise, this actually beats Mathematica's built-in `Sort` function:

```
n = 1000000;
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n];
r1 = quicksortiterative[a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = Sort[a]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 0.105
>
> 0.127
>
> True

Comment: I wonder what sort of generalizations or inefficiencies built-in `Sort` uses that allows this to be faster... I would have assumed that'd be implemented as efficiently as possible.

Comment: So thought I. But `Sort` can sort everything. This can only sort real numbers. 20% is not that much of a performance loss if you take `Sort`'s flexibility into account, is it? Moreover, the pre-allocated memory for stack is definately oversized; it should need only $O(\log_2(n))$ of memory. But you would need some routines to handle stack overflow... I am sure that `Sort` is implemented somewhat cleverer in that regard.

Comment: I guess I assumed that `Sort` would dispatch to the fastest routine if, say, it had a `PackedArray` of numbers. I suppose it could make sense with respect to a memory/speed tradeoff.

Comment: To my great amusement, on my machine your implementation is exactly 20% faster and uses exactly 20% more memory. (I got that from this: ``rm1 = MaxMemoryUsed[{rt1, r1} = RepeatedTiming@quicksortiterative[a];];
rm2 = MaxMemoryUsed[{rt2, r2} = RepeatedTiming@Sort[a];];
(rt1 - rt2)/rt1
N@(rm1 - rm2)/rm1``

Comment: Oh, it does dispatch. Example: `n = 1000000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}];
a = Sort[A]; // AbsoluteTiming
B = A; b = B[[1, 1]]; B[[1, 1]] = 1; B[[1, 1]] = b;
b = Sort[B]; // AbsoluteTiming`...

Comment: That's good to know. Also likely a source of subtle bugs and performance degradations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think the important message from your post is that the recursive-compiled-function approach used for the benchmark is not "the Mathematica way to do it". Note how this is part of many Q&As here on SE, as is code optimization for performance in general. I feel that developers have to acquire quite a big amount of knowledge about the Mathematica language until they are really proficient in writing efficient code. The benchmark results illustrate *this* fact, rather than qualifying Mathematica as being slower than other languages.